# How to build a library around spring-boot that doesn't enforce a certain spring-boot version?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to build a library https://github.com/mhewedy/spring-data-jpa-mongodb-expressions on top of spring boot and spring Data JPA.

What I want to achieve and hence the library doesn't use explicitly implementation feature of spring boot or spring data JPA, I need to make this a library to take the version from the including project.

Currently, the version of spring boot is defined in the [pom.xml](https://github.com/mhewedy/spring-data-jpa-mongodb-expressions/blob/d5a7858caf46909fd1891cb3b463f9808621bf77/pom.xml#L9)

So, I think once I uploaded the jar to the maven repository, and whenever anybody depends on this jar, there might be a conflict in the spring dependencies (that comes from his project and what comes from this jar)

So my question is If I make the dependencies in pom.xml as Optional, do this will solve the problem? if not what other alternative solutions I can do?

**EDIT:**

Here's a list of types from spring I use in the library:

```
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
org.springframework.data.repository.NoRepositoryBean;
org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification;
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformation;
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository;
```

Comment: It depends on what you use. If you use interfaces, classes from certain Spring (Boot) versions you are strictly said bound to that version for compatibility reasons. There is no guarantee that an interface (especially internal ones) are still available in other versions or that methods have been added you need to implement etc.

Comment: @M.Deinum I use a few list of them (see updates), I don't need to tie my lib with a certain version of spring, as it will be useless. is there any alternative?

Comment: Those aren't from Spring those are from Spring Data JPA and with using those classes you basically tie them to Spring Data JPA and also that certain range (as things chance between versions). If you are using Spring Data JPA 2.x to build this this will definitely not work with version 1.x (as classes you use didn't exists, had a different contract or moved to different packages).

Answer (score 2):

For building your library, you need to use a given version of the dependencies. You need to choose one, otherwise the compiler cannot create a classpath and compile your code.

Somebody who uses your library might use another version of the dependencies. Their versions will (usually) override your versions because they win in the Maven dependency mediation. So your library will actually run with the versions that the library user specifies (if the library user does not use your dependencies, then your versions are still there).

So, the question that remains is: Will your code work with a newer/different version of the dependencies?

This cannot be said in general because it depends on the way the maintainer of the dependencies works.